# Ruby: undefined method 'update'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rake

I know similar topics have been asked before, however this is coming from a git repo from here: https://github.com/obfuscurity/descartes which I downloaded and did my best in following the sparse directions the author posted.

Here's where I'm at right now:

After doing foreman start I get this output:

```
/services/descartes-master/lib/descartes/models/metrics.rb:28:in `update': undefined method `update' for MetricCacheInfo:Class (NoMethodError)
```

Here is the rest of the output:

```
16:36:17 web.1  |       from /services/descartes-master/lib/descartes/model/metrics.rb:17:in `load'
16:36:17 web.1  |       from /services/descartes-master/config.ru:28:in `block in <main>'
16:36:17 web.1  |       from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
16:36:17 web.1  |       from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
16:36:17 web.1  |       from /services/descartes-master/config.ru:in `new'
16:36:17 web.1  |       from /services/descartes-master/config.ru:in `<main>'
16:36:17 web.1  |       from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
16:36:17 web.1  |       from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
16:36:17 web.1  |       from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
16:36:17 web.1  |       from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:277:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
16:36:17 web.1  |       from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:199:in `app'
16:36:17 web.1  |       from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:314:in `wrapped_app'
16:36:17 web.1  |       from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:250:in `start'
16:36:17 web.1  |       from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:141:in `start'
16:36:17 web.1  |       from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rack-1.5.2/bin/rackup:4:in `<top (required)>'
16:36:17 web.1  |       from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin/rackup:23:in `load'
16:36:17 web.1  |       from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin/rackup:23:in `<main>'
16:36:17 web.1  |       from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
16:36:17 web.1  |       from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
16:36:17 web.1  | exited with code 1
16:36:17 system | sending SIGTERM to all processes
```

As you can see I'm using rvm and bundle with ruby version 1.9.3

Here is the code for the metrics.rb:28 file: https://github.com/obfuscurity/descartes/blob/master/lib/descartes/models/metrics.rb

Let me know if there's any additional information I can provide.
Thanks

Comment: In update you are redirecting to a path which is not present just neeed to define method for index

Comment: run command rake route and check your routes which you have already defined in ur application

Comment: Thanks SSP for replying. I know this might be a little aggravating, but to be honest I have no clue what I'm doing; doing a lot of rtfm..ing.


You mentioned when I update, I'm redirecting to a path which isn't present. how do I define the method for the index exactly?


I run command: rake route I'm at home right now and this is for work which I will not have access to until Monday, what exactly do I do once I run the command and what am I particularly looking for...?

What do you mean as far as that I have routes already defined in my application?

Comment: Also I noticed on other submissions on stackoverflow as well as on youtube tutorials, the config/database.yml file is generated for you once you do a command such as: 
`bundle exec rake db:migrate:up` or something which complains that the role 'user' doesn't exist, but that's a different issue I'm faced with entirely.

Comment: @SPP I went ahead and tried to run the command `rake route` and `rake routes` however I just receive an error: `Don't know how to build task 'route'` Going to see about looking into if there's anything I'm missing. The instructions for supposedly 'running' the sinatra web app is detailed here: https://github.com/obfuscurity/descartes